# How to modify a scope variable with ng-click in a button and reflect the change immediately in one of the buttons attributes

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-ng-click

## Scenario

I have a `button` (created via a directive) that looks like below (after being rendered via the directive):

```
<button class="btn btn-sm btn-primary" create-element="row" ng-click="setSettings([{span: 6}, {span: 6}], create);" settings="{}" data-dismiss="modal">One half block<button>
```

**Note:** The `settings` attribute of the button is bound to `$scope.settings` object.

The code in my controller is as follows:

```
$scope.settings = {};              // the settings object that I want to bind to the button

// function to be called if I'd want to set some data to the settings variable from the button
$scope.setSettings = function (setting, callback){ 
    $scope.settings = setting;
    callback();
};

$scope.create = function () {
    $log.log($attrs.settings);        // always reflects data set from previous click event 
    var settings = $attrs.settings;
    var type = $attrs.createElement;
    var element = DOMService(type, settings);
    getTarget().append($compile(element)($scope));
};
```

### Problem

*I'd want to produce a two way binding via the `ng-click` directive so that any change in the variable `settings` is reflected in one of the buttons own attributes.*

The first click on the button does change the `$scope.settings` object but the change isn't there in the button's `settings` attribute. So, upon every second click, the data that was set in the previous click is reflected in the attribute.

When the button is clicked, it calls the `setSettings()` function via which I'm passing an arbitrary settings object, and soon after, the `callback` is called. The problem is that when the `settings` object is set to some value with the click on the button, I cannot reflect the change occurring in it immediately in the view.

I know that a two way binding for instance on an `input[type=text]` is possible via `ng-model` directive. So I'm able to produce a two way binding as such:

```
<input class="input-sm form-control" ng-model="settings" placeholder="Title" />
```

and to reflect the change (*in `settings` object*), I can echo the object out in, say, another button in this way:

```
<button ng-click="create()" settings="settings" data-dismiss="modal">Create</button>
```

***So, how do I achieve the same two-way binding through the `ng-click` directive. And if, the way I'm wanting to achieve this is wrong, then what is the appropriate one?***

Comment: Can we see the directive code?

Comment: @Michelem, their is actually a custom-built service injected (in the same directive, the controller for which is shown above) which takes JS object and renders it into a dialog as a DOM node. For instance, the button shown above is created from a Javascript object as: `{ button: {attrs: {'ng-click': 'setSettings(...)', class: 'btn btn-....'}, content: 'Add'} }`.

Comment: will you provide any fiddle?

Comment: Okay, I will make a fiddle.